# How to connect with wifi network using IP Address in iOS?

Tags: swift, sockets, tcp, ip-address, cfstream

First of all i will explain what i want to achieve. I have a WIFI Bridge. Now right now I'm connected with that bridge via iPhone device. I can see the name of wifi bridge by going into setting and select wifi.

Now from here I want to get connect with the WIFI using ip address and port number and write some data. Below is the code for reference:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                           "192.168.29.1" as CFString,
                                           1717,
                                           &readStream,
                                           &writeStream)

    inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

    inputStream.delegate = self

    inputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
    outputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)

    inputStream.open()
    outputStream.open()
```

But I'm not able to connect with that IP Address. I also confirm the ip via going into setting.

[image]

I tried multiple things like Socket.io , web-socket, Stream etc. but not able to connect with that ip.

Thanks in advance.